# Debugging multiple symbols with GDB using Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, gdb, stm32, bootloader, debug-symbols

I am working on a STM32 project which has a bootloader. Microcontroller boots with the bootloader and then jumps to the application. In order to debug the application correctly after jump operation, I use the GDB command below:

```
add-symbol-file application.elf 0x080603B0
```

With the command above, I can have all the debug symbols for the application without any problem. I can debug whatever I want.

Lately, I added a source file called `foo.c` in both projects. In this file, there is a variable called `bar`. The projects are compiled and linked successfully without any problem. Up to now, all is good. When I debug `bar` in the bootloader code, I can see its value correctly but after I jump to the application and try to debug `bar` in the application, the watch window shows me a wrong value (because the address of bar in the application side is different).

I dumped my two executables (bootloader.elf and application.elf) and verified that the address of `bar` in each executable is different, which is normal. I noted the absolute address of `bar` in each executable and debugged those absolute addresses. Violà... I have correct values for each `bar` variable.

I am using Visual Studio Code's debug feature which uses GDB and openocd behind. My debug configuration seems to be correct as I can debug everything unless there are duplicated symbols.

I suspect that I am having difficulty of debugging multiple symbols.

How can I debug my projects when I have multiple symbols? What is the problem in my situation and how can I solve this problem?